# difference between hook and method events in upstart

Tags: ubuntu, upstart

What is the difference between hooks and methods in upstart events.

As I understand both force the emitter to wait for the tasks to complete that were started due to the emission a hook or method event. However what is the difference between them ?

http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#system-job - Sections 4.3.12 and 4.3.13

Answer (score 0):

I see an ASCII text footnote where the second table gives another detail.  They spelled it in unclear terms.

http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#ubuntu-well-known-events-ubuntu-specific

```
Table 2: Event Types.

   +------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
   | Ref | Event Type | Notes                                                           |
   |-----+------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------|
   |  H  | Hook       | Blocking. Waits for events that start on or stop on this event. |
   |-----+------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------|
   |  M  | Method     | Blocking task.                                                  |
   |-----+------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------|
   |  S  | Signal     | Non-blocking.                                                   |
   +------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Table 1 tells which standard events belong to which category.

I could imagine that methods return an exit code and hooks could always carry a successful code.

I see another problem for which I did not see an answer in the cook book.  When OR connects hook names in a "start on" clause, I can imagine the callee returning control of the caller's thread immediately.  But I do not know if AND-connected hook names will block all callers until the last one calls (emits).  This gets murkier with hook names connected by ANDs and ORs in a single clause.